# How long does it take for APNS/FCM to provide feedback to Amazon SNS that a given device token is invalid?

Tags: amazon-web-services, firebase, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, amazon-sns

I am using Amazon SNS in order to send push notifications to my React Native mobile app. There is a requirement to cleanup the Topics/Subscriptions in SNS when a given user uninstalls the mobile application or leaves the company (the app will be remotely wiped once the user leaves the department/company).

I've done some research in SNS documentation and found out that it is up to APNS and FCM to notify SNS that a given device token associated to a particular installation of the app on that device is invalid. I do see disabled Endpoints in SNS (meaning that at some point APNS/FCM did provide feedback to SNS about invalid token), however, I need to know how long does it take for this feedback to get delivered to SNS. I tired to uninstall the application from our test iOS device and send a notification through SNS console to the device and the console returned a successful delivery message:

> Message published to endpoint 
>   arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:ACCOUNT_ID:endpoint/APNS/APP_ID/ENDPOINT_ID
>   successfully.

I need to know the time it takes for APNS/FCM to provide the feedback in order to implement a scheduled cleanup process involving deletion of disabled endpoints in SNS.

This is my first question on StackOverflow, I am glad I joined this community!

Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: Hi. Did you find any useful information about that ?

I always get success when sending to uninstalled app.
with Firebase devices it will get disabled later and next push will fail. That's when I cleanup entry from my DB.
But with APNS, SNS never get any update about my iOS devices so they keep stacking.. That is pretty annoying